# How to create Bot Authentication?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, bots, botframework

I've created a bot that I want to secure. I discovered the option to add Authentication to my bot's app service on Azure:

[image: Azure Authentication Settings Picture]

I set up a Microsoft Authentication feature that seems to work, but what do I need to add to my bot's code to get a user to login/ to authenticate someone. Could you provide a step-by-step solution, I am very new to this. I am using the .NET framework (c#).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So, what you want to do is have users talk to your bot and at some point ask them to authenticate against X provider? What language are u using?

Comment: I would like to ask them to authenticate against MSFT at the beginning of  a conversation only. I am using c#

Comment: Yes, you don't need to secure the app service. All need to be handled via code in your bot. I will close the question as a duplicate and point you to the previous questions where this was discussed.

Comment: And basically any other thread from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbotframework%5D+authbot) discussed this scenario.

Comment: It may be the same with WebApi. We may could get more detail steps from the [azure official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet).